# Ffmpeg scroll text from right to left position top

Tags: ffmpeg

I want run text over video, i have try this command

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -vf "drawtext=text='Test Test':fontfile=arial.ttf:y=h-line_h-10:x=w-mod(max(t-4.5\,0)*(w+tw)/5.5\,(w+tw)):fontcolor=white:fontsize=40:shadowx=2:shadowy=2" "out.mp4"
```

But problem is because i want run only once this text, and should be located on top, now with this command text is located at the bottom and repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` and `y` expressions should be

```
y=10:x=w-(t-4.5)*(w+tw)/5.5
```

The text will be drawn 10 pixels from the top. It will scroll once from right to left, starting at 4.5 seconds and disappear after scrolling for 5.5 seconds.